# Add a "breaker" for listview

Tags: android

I'd like to separate some group of cells from others, for example by date.
Is it possible?
Something like this:

```
cell content1
cell content2
breaker 
cell content1
cell content2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one out:

http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

If you want to do it completely by yourself, you can set the list's adapter
to work with multiple view's, using the methods:

getItemViewType(int)

getViewTypeCount()

read more here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Comment: AmazingListview is simply...amazing! :)